# GridBagLayout constraints not working?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

Here is my code that uses `GridbagLayout`

```
public IntroPanel(){
    JPanel intro = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Test test test");
    label1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 40));
    label1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("test2 test2 test2");

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,480));
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    gbc.gridx = 10;
    gbc.gridy = 10;
    gbc.weightx = 0;
    add(label1, gbc);

    gbc.gridx = 20;
    gbc.gridy = 10;
    add(label2, gbc);
}
```

I changed all the `gridx`, `gridy`, `GridBagConstraints` to align them but nothing is working. `NORTHEAST` for grid constraints is not working either. Can anyone help? Learning how to create my own GUI..

Main coding is here

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title111111111");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JTabbedPane tp = new JTabbedPane();

    tp.addTab("Intro", new IntroPanel());
    tp.addTab("Catalogue", new CataloguePanel());

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(tp);
    frame.pack();

    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Is this the exact code you have? It doesn't look like this will compile. Is it `public class IntroPanel` and all your code is in `main`? Or is this some other method?

Comment: I added the main codings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
add(label1, gbc);
```

is adding to `this` (the `IntroPanel`).

What you probably mean is this:

```
intro.add(label1, gbc);
```

EDIT:

Try adding `setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` before the `add`s

Comment: It will just go blank with nothing haha

Comment: @John I think you might need to call `setLayout(new GridBagLayout())`?

Comment: If you are using GridBagConstraints, you always need to set the layout of the component you want to use them on to GridBagLayout. So the answer is corect, you need to call `setLayout(new GridBagLayout());` before calling `add(label1, gbc);`

Comment: @kuporific I have another question. If I do gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST; why doesnt it go top left?

Comment: @John Because you dont have any weight assigned to `gbc.weighty`

Comment: @Reimeus So do I just do gbc.weighty = 1; gbc.weightx = 1; to align them tog top and bottom?

Comment: Those weights need to be set to move the components from center. They _should_ align. Try it

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I understnad how to use weighty and x now